# Hibernate: many to one mapping with different database tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 classes: `User` and `Branch`. many user can have one branch. 
I.e. this is association many-to-one. 
My `users` table is in first database called `fi` and the `branch` table in the second database called `fi-master`.

I am facing this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table user refers to an unmapped class: com.hcl.fi.web.model.Branch
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1134)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1052)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:997)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:720)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 100 more
```

How can I map them?

in `user` hbm :

```
  <many-to-one name="branchDetail" column="branch_id"  class="com.hcl.fi.web.model.Branch" cascade="all"  
          not-found="ignore" not-null="true"/>
```

Comment: You might have forgotten to add `@Entity` on the class `Branch`. Depending on your configuration, you might also need to declare `Branch` in `persistence.xml`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle He uses a `xml` mapping.

Comment: Please, add an information about Hibernate version, and all yor xml mappings and configuration code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please look at below

- You should have a entity class called 'Branch' under the path
  'com.hcl.fi.web.model'. It should be decalred as @Entity.
- Make sure that 'Branch.hbm.xml' file is same location as 'User.hbm.xml' 
  Please make sure that path correction if needed for 'Branch'.